# Loopback: How to submit a multipart/form-data upload in loopback-component-storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, multipartform-data, loopback

loopback-component-storage doc for file (or files) upload says this:
[loopback documentation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/Storage+component)

Description:

> Upload one or more files into the specified container. The request
>   body must use multipart/form-data which the file input type for HTML
>   uses.

Method:

> upload(req, res, cb)

REST URI:

> POST
>   /api/containers/:container/upload

Would someone please show an example of how to create this multipart/form request in Angular/Javascript?

Answer (score 4):

You can go through code in [Loopback Storage example](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-storage) git repository. It internally uses [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) library which would be beneficial in the future to add filtering on the type, size and number of files.

This example doesn't use `lb-services` but uses direct calls using `$http` module.

You'll be able to upload files using the example code. Please let me know in case you need to know angular-file-upload filters to filter out files based on size, type or number of files.

Comment: I'm using `$http` module, too, so I guess I'm on the right track. I was hoping `lb-services` could be used, because of course the scaffolding gets created for the remote upload method, but it can't really be used.